# composer failed to open stream: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known

Tags: php, composer-php, lumen

I'm new in lumen and i have done

`composer clear-cache` then after

`composer update`

to install some package after configurating **composer.json**
however i have got this error:

```
[Composer\Downloader\TransportException]                                     
  The "http://packagist.org/p/phpunit/php-timer%24be3efc71adf134c858c1add0117  
  f060f4ab545fe9d357983c7bea165b2008d65.json" file could not be downloaded: p  
  hp_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known       
  failed to open stream: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name o  
  r service not known
```

Plase how could i fix this error

Comment: Are you connected to the internet?

Comment: yes but sometimes newtwork fallen down under 35kb/s

Comment: Looks like you will have to do this sort of thing only when you have a good network connection. Remember composer gets these packages from the internet and not by magic

Comment: ok thnk u because i have try it several time when i still  connected

Comment: Thank u @RiggsFolly yes i have to have a good network to de composer update which mean to avoid this kind of error. I have deconnected all devices that i reached to update. thank u again

Answer (score 7):

This issue was posted about 2 years ago but I wanna answer this problem so 
no one should have difficulty like me.

First open /etc/resolv.conf

(if you using Ubuntu distributions, the file is /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head)

```
# cat /etc/resolve.conf
```

And after that, write this rows to the file:

```
# Google's public DNS servers
nameserver 8.8.8.8    # Primary DNS server
nameserver 8.8.4.4    # Secondary DNS server
```

These are the Google's public DNS servers as mentioned in the code above.

Save and close.

After restart the network service using this command:

```
service network restart
```

This solved my problem.

Hope help to others...

Answer (score 2):

I fixed the issue on Linux/Centos6 (Plesk Onyx) by:

Opening /etc/resolv.conf (my file was empty)

Added:
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4

options rotate
options timeout:3

Hopefully this helps someone out there.

Answer (score 1):

In my case was a dns misconfiguration in Vagrant VM.

Updating DNS in /etc/resolv.conf solved my issue: https://askubuntu.com/questions/897270/dns-cannot-resolve-hosts

hope this will help other users

Answer (score 0):

In case someone in the future needs this...

If you're using docker it's likely you're having DNS issues from inside the container. Basically the fix is :

Find out your network's DNS server :`nmcli dev show | grep 'IP4.DNS'` (let's say it gives `10.0.0.2`)

then update `/etc/docker/daemon.json` like so :

```
{
    "dns": ["10.0.0.2", "8.8.8.8"]
}
```

of course replacing `10.0.0.2` with yours. Then don't forget to `sudo service docker restart`.

Answer (score -1):

I tried using root user and it's working fine.

I was also facing the same error while installing few modules and also composer update.

Tried `sudo su` to login as root and ran composer command.

Comment: It is not the recommendation, as Composer said: "Do not run Composer as root/super user! See https://getcomposer.org/root for details." Please, don't do it!!!